# Implementing a mod 12 counter in SystemC

Tags: counter, systemc

How do I go about implementing a modulus 12 counter in SystemC? I am new to the library and do not have much experience with it. please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you just have to code it up there is nothing special going to help.  Something like this...

```
sc_uint<4> counter;

sc_uint<4> increment(){
  counter++;
  if(counter >=12){
    counter =0;
  }
  return (counter);
}
```

Things are a lot better if you can avoid having none power of 2 stuff.